# Which is costlier : sending extra fields in payload or equivalent regex test at backend

Tags: java, node.js, spring, spring-boot, backend

Is it costlier to send extra fields in request body or to run a regex at the server and compute the equivalent of extra fields?

For example: frontend application has two input fields for domestic and international number but the user can only enter one of them. Assuming the backend needs to know if its a domestic or international number, which seems to be a better payload sent by front end:

```
{
    "phoneNumber":"(+123)45567891",
    "isInternational":true
}
```

OR

```
{
    "phoneNumber":"(+123)45567891",
}
```

and check by regex test if "+123" is domestic or international at the backend?

Comment: I think "which is costlier" is the wrong question to ask here 99% of the time.  The very first question you should ask is: do you trust the client to make that decision for you and what would the consequences be if they lied to you? What would happen if you got `{ "phoneNumber": "abcd", "isInternational": true }`? In this specific case, probably not an awful lot, but in the general case that seems like a serious security issue.

Comment: Thanks  @JoachimSauer never thought in that direction and I have got my answer to my the question now but I am curious  now if we over look the security and other aspects - which will be a costlier?

Comment: That's really hard to say in the general case because both parsing one extra field and applying a simple regex to a short input string are fairly cheap operations, so which one exactly will end up being faster is not an easy answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that neither are particularly computationally expensive, so either solution would work. This is a design decision.

However, I would usually write the validation logic on the server-side, and leave as little up to the frontend as possible. You would have to perform validation on the input regardless, so it makes sense to perform this check here too.